# Unset Fn Key Activating Expose

Tags: keyboard, expose

When I first got my Macbook Pro, I somewhere came across a setting that let me map the Fn key to the same action as the 'F3' command, which I guess is the 'Expose' feature where it shows all open windows.

Since that was set, I've been unable to find where to UNset it, because now I'm unable to use Fn + Function Key to activate F1, F2, etc.

I've checked the Keyboard preferences, but all Expose options show they are mapped to the usual F1-12 keys, with no reference anywhere to Fn.

I've also clicked the Reset to Defaults button there, but no change.

Any ideas where I can find this?

Comment: You set a setting that let you press just Fn to open Expose?

Comment: That's correct... and I have no idea where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I open "Expose & Spaces" preference panel,  I see an option to select the "fn" key to different Expose actions.  This is on 10.6.

[image: Expose and Spaces Preference Panel]

Comment: This is very different from what I see on 10.6.7.  My menus list only the F1-F13 keys, plus "Secondary" and "Middle" mouse buttons.

Comment: @Austin Mine shows these same options under 10.6.7, and doesn't show mouse options. Is this the "All Windows" leftmost menu you're clicking?

Comment: @Matthew Ah, you're right -- I was clicking the menu under the "Dashboard" section.  +1 for this answer.

Comment: @Matthew I think you meant to address that last comment to @Ian?  ;]  And I already mentioned that to him in a comment on the question above.

Comment: @Austin Sorry, you're right.

Comment: I also see this screen, however, the Fn key was not displayed as the All windows key, which said F9. When I opened the drop down and re-selected the already-selected F9, the Fn key stopped performing the All window expose action. Display bug!